# Azure DevOps Task Control Option: Cannot Change "Run this task" dropdown

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps, so please forgive me if my query seems a tad silly.

I'm trying to change our build definition so that it will miss certain steps based on the value of a Pipeline variable. So, if I'm correct, I believe that I first must change the **Run this task** selection (found under **Control Options**) to **Custom conditions** (its current value is **Only when all previous tasks have succeeded**). However, everytime I try this, the original is reinstated. It's as though I don't have the proper permissions, but I'm certainly able to change and save other properties. I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do other browsers have the same issue?

Comment: Hi friend, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Please check if you have the same issue in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1144119/run-this-task-takes-many-attempts-before-option-se.html).

Comment: Hi Walter. Sorry for the late reply. We are using Chrome, but I've found a way around the issue, as described below. We've not tried with other browsers yet. And it appears that the ticket you've provided describes exactly the behaviour I've found. Thanks for your input :). Regards, David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who responded. I've just tried again, and got it working. The "trick" involved is to make the selection using the arrow keys, and not the mouse. A colleague has also verified this quite odd behaviour.

The browser we are using is Chrome.

Regards,
David.